# Tomcat "no method found" error on server startup

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I'm currently working on a Spring dynamic web project. On Tomcat startup, I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.io.ResourceEditor.<init> 
(Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;)V
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:102)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have viewed several other questions regarding this issue, and the suggested problem is a dependency issue. I went and changed the version of springframework.core to a previous version, but this changed nothing.

Pom.xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
    instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
    4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Spring-mvc-Test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring-mvc-Test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Spring-mvc-Test</name>
    <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <type>dtd</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

How do I fix this problem? How do I diagnose an issue like this accurately in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mess in your dependencies. I see Spring Boot dependency. Are you trying to create Spring Boot project? If so, go to https://start.spring.io Also most important thing with Spring is to make sure that all base Spring libraries have the same version. To help you with that Maven BOM mechanism exists (btw. similar technique is used in Spring Boot): https://www.baeldung.com/spring-maven-bom

Comment: I'm trying to create just a spring mvc project, void of Spring Boot at the moment. I also tried removing the spring boot dependency, but I still have the same error on Tomcat startup

Comment: Then don’t use any spring boot dependency and in order to manage spring boot dependencies use this BOM: https://javalibs.com/bom/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies (this can be used even in non-spring boot project). And also read about BOM files from Baeldung website or from elsewhere. It’s really important concept nowadays and you will surely use it in every project.